# Alternative of send_file() in flask on Pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pythonanywhere, x-sendfile

I am new to python and still learning. I created a small python 3.6 Flask webapp on pythonanwhere and found out that send_file() is not working on pythonanywhere servers. I am actively looking for an alternative to download an excel file directly on the user machine. I also tried **Response** but it is not giving desired output. 
I read alot about it online and found that the send_file works fine if we set below

**wsgi-disable-file-wrapper = True**

However, i don't know where to set this as i couldn't find uWsgi.ini file where i could update this line.

Below are the methods which i tried but they failed, please help

***SEND_FILE() configuration:*** ->>> Not running..

```
    output = BytesIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    workbook = writer.book
    output.seek(0)
    return send_file(output,attachment_filename="testing.xlsx",as_attachment=True)
```

***Output Error:***

```
return environ.get('wsgi.file_wrapper', FileWrapper)(file, buffer_size)
SystemError: <built-in function uwsgi_sendfile> returned a result with an error set
```

***With Response configuration:***

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("abc.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

return Response(writer,mimetype="text/csv",headers={"Content-disposition":"attachment; filename=myplot.csv"})
```

***Output error:***

```
Error running WSGI application
TypeError: '_XlsxWriter' object is not iterable
File "/home/hridesh1987/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 870, in __next__return self._next()
File "/home/hridesh1987/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 83, in _iter_encoded
for item in iterable:
```

Comment: how did you find out that send_file doesn't work on PythonAnywhere? to my knowledge it should work?

Comment: @conrad see https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/8612/

Answer (score 11):

I raised the same issue on the PythonAnywhere forums and they gave me [this response](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/13570/). Kudos to 'glenn' of the PythonAnywhere staff.

Copy-pasted:

```
from io import BytesIO
from flask import Flask, Response
from werkzeug import FileWrapper

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    b = BytesIO(b"blah blah blah")
    w = FileWrapper(b)
    return Response(w, mimetype="text/plain", direct_passthrough=True)
```

I adapted it slightly for my usage. I set the filename via the `Content-Disposition` header. I also had to tweak the `FileWrapper` import, and `data` is already a `BytesIO` object in my code:

```
from flask import Response
from werkzeug.wsgi import FileWrapper

def send_excel_file(data, filename):
    # See: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/13570/
    file_wrapper = FileWrapper(data)
    headers = {
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(filename)
    }
    response = Response(file_wrapper,
                        mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                        direct_passthrough=True,
                        headers=headers)
    return response
```

Answer (score 3):

From the mentioned forum in Mat's answer I verified that:

> [`send_file()`] does not work because the uWSGI file wrapper does not support file-like objects, only real files

...but applying Mat's solution still throws me a **ValueError: I/O operation on closed file**. Even with FileWrapper class.

This way is even simpler: If you use a file_pointer based on `io` eg. `io.StringIO()` you must use `Response()` instead. Not with a *fp* but sending the content directly. Based on your code:

```
with BytesIO() as output:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    output.seek(0)
    headers = {"Content-disposition": "attachment; filename=testing.xlsx"}
    mimetype = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    return Response(output.read(), mimetype=mimetype, headers=headers)
```

Comment: what does ` workbook = writer.book` do, looks like its not being used

Comment: You are correct, but that part was in his code. I tried not to change his example, but now it's fixed. The important part is the `Response()` change, reading `io.BytesIO()` object, so I didn't pass a pointer but bytes() instead.