# Matplot-pillow animation rendering broken images on cpanel server

Tags: matplotlib, flask, cpanel, bytesio

My matplotlib-pillow animation flask app in cpanel python app deployment displays broken images when I access my flask definitions with the Play, Reset, and Save Figure javascript buttons on the html file. The rest of the html renders and operates correctly.

I tested this on my windows home server (127.0.0.0:5000).  It rendered everything correctly, but not on the CPanel correctly. The CPanel environment is in a passenger-wsgi.py that I cannot edit (I have tried). I realize that the send _file might be the problem.  I have tried the FileWrapper and flask.Response combo suggested here for the PythonAnywhere [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087728/alternative-of-send-file-in-flask-on-pythonanywhere) thinking this might apply to the CPanel hosting. I have tried to directly return the base64 with ut-8 encode solution from the update and save_fig definations in my app.py. The plots continue to not render for any of these solutions.

Here is my app.py

```
rom werkzeug.wsgi import FileWrapper
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from io import BytesIO
import base64
from PIL import Image
import os
import numpy as np

app = Flask(__name__)

numpoints=20

def constants(x0,y0,v0,theta):
    global v0st
    v0st=str(v0)
    ay=-9.81
    theta0=np.radians(theta)
    vx0=v0*np.cos(theta0)
    vy0=v0*np.sin(theta0)
    yrange=((vy0**2)/(2*-ay))+y0
    trange=(vy0/-ay)+(np.sqrt(((vy0/-ay)**2)+((2*y0)/-ay)))
    xrange=(trange*vx0)+x0
    xconst_list=[x0,vx0]
    yconst_list=[y0,vy0,ay]
    return [xconst_list,yconst_list,trange,xrange,yrange,theta]

def x(t,c):
    x=(c[1]*t)+ c[0]
    return x

def y(t,c):
    y=((c[2]*(t**2))/2)+(c[1]*t)+c[0]
    return y

def line_int(con):
    ca=con
    num=int(ca[2]*numpoints)
    tm=np.linspace(0,ca[2],num)

    # Initialize the plot
    
    global fig
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    line0, = ax.plot(x(tm,const[0]),y(tm,ca[1]),label=str(const[5])+" Degrees")

    ax.set_xlim(0.0, ca[3])
    ax.set_ylim(0.0, ca[4])

    plt.title("Projectile Motion (Initial Velocity="+v0st+" m/s)")
    plt.xlabel("x-aixs (m)")
    plt.ylabel("y-axis (m)")
    
    ax.legend([line0],[line0.get_label()])
    return line0

# Function to update the plot in each frame of the animation
def update(frame,line,con):
    ca=con
    newline=line
    num=int(ca[2]*numpoints)
    tm=np.linspace(0,ca[2],num)
    newline.set_xdata(x(frame/numpoints - tm,ca[0]))
    newline.set_ydata(y(frame/numpoints - tm,ca[1])) 
    return line

# Function to generate and encode the plot as a base64 string
def generate_plot():
    buffer = BytesIO()
    num=int(const[2]*numpoints)
    img_paths=[]

    # Save individual frames as PNG images
    for frame in range(10):
        update(frame,line1,const)
        fig.savefig(buffer, format='png')
        buffer.seek(0)

        # Convert PNG to RGB image
        img = Image.open(buffer)
        img = img.convert('RGB')
        pathf='/home/airandspace/projectiledemo/static/'+f'frame_{frame}.png'
        img_paths.append(pathf)
        img.save(pathf)

    # Create a GIF from the saved frames
    img = Image.open(img_paths[0])
    img.save(buffer, format='GIF', save_all=True, append_images=[Image.open(img_path) for img_path in img_paths[1:]], duration=num, loop=0)

    # Close and remove temporary PNG files
    for img_path in img_paths:
        os.remove(img_path)

    plt.close(fig)
    buffer.seek(0)
    encoded_plot = base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode('utf-8')
    return f'data:image/gif;base64,{encoded_plot}'

# Route to render the HTML page
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index6.html')

@app.route("/demo", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def demo():
    if request.method == "POST":
        xi=float(request.form["xint"])
        yi=float(request.form["yint"])
        vi=float(request.form["velocity"])
        thetai=float(request.form["angle"]) 
        global const
        const=constants(xi,yi,vi,thetai)
        global line1
        line1=line_int(const)
        num=int(const[2]*numpoints)
        return render_template("plot6.html",fig=generate_plot(),nump=num )
    else:
        return render_template("index6.html")

# Route to handle dynamic updates of the w
@app.route('/update_plot/<int:frame>')
def update_plot(frame):
    buffer = BytesIO()
    update(frame,line1,const)
    fig.savefig(buffer, format='png')
    plt.close(fig)
    buffer.seek(0)
    return send_file(buffer,mimetype='image/png')

# Route to handle slider updates
@app.route('/update_slider', methods=['POST'])
def update_slider():
    frame = int(request.form['frame'])
    buffer = BytesIO()
    update(frame,line1,const)
    fig.savefig(buffer, format='png')
    plt.close(fig)
    buffer.seek(0)
    return send_file(buffer,mimetype='image/png')

# Route to handle saving the current figure
@app.route('/save_fig')
def save_fig():
    frame = int(request.args.get('frame', 0))
    update(frame,line1,const)
    
    # Save the current figure as a PNG image
    buffer = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buffer,format='png')
    buffer.seek(0)

    # Send the saved figure as a downloadable file
    return send_file(buffer, mimetype='image/png', as_attachment=True, download_name=f'figure_frame_{frame}.png')
    
# Start the Flask app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

my plot6.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{%block content %}
    <h3>Your Projectile!</h3>
    <div id="plot-container">
        <img id="plot-image" src="{{ fig }}" alt="Plot">
    </div>

    <label for="frame-slider">Frame:</label>
    <input type="range" id="frame-slider" min="0" max="num" value="0" oninput="updateSlider(this.value)">
    <p>Frame: <span id="frame-value">0</span></p>

    <button onclick="startAnimation()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="stopAnimation()">Stop</button>
    <button onclick="resetAnimation()">Reset</button>
    <button onclick="saveFig()">Save Fig</button>

    <script>
        var frame = 0;
        var intervalId;

        function startAnimation() {
            intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                updateSlider(frame);
                frame += 1;
                document.getElementById('plot-image').src = `/update_plot/${frame}`;
            }, 1000);
        }

        function stopAnimation() {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }

        function resetAnimation() {
            frame = 0;
            document.getElementById('plot-image').src = `/update_plot/${frame}`;
            updateSlider(frame);
        }

        function saveFig() {
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = `/save_fig?frame=${frame}`;
            link.download = `figure_frame_${frame}.png`;
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);

            // Manually set the slider value to match the saved frame
            document.getElementById('frame-slider').value = frame;
            document.getElementById('frame-value').innerText = frame;
        }

        function updateSlider(value) {
            frame = parseInt(value);
            document.getElementById('frame-slider').value = frame;
            document.getElementById('frame-value').innerText = frame;
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

and my baset.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
<title>Projectile Demonstration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2"><h1>Projectile Motion Demonstration</h1>    
        <h2>Enter the properties of the projectile!</h2>
    </th>    
    <tr>
    <td>
    {% block nav %}    
    <table>
    <form action="{{url_for("demo")}}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
        <tr>
            <td><label for="Angle">Angle (degrees))</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Angle" name="angle" placeholder="Enter the angle."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td><label for="Velocity">Velocity (m/s)</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="Velocity" name="velocity" placeholder="Enter the velocity."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td><label for="InitialX">Initial X position (m)</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="IntialX" name="xint" placeholder="Enter the initial x position."></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td><label for="InitialY">Initial Y position(m)</label></td> 
            <td><input type="text" id="InitialY" name="yint" placeholder="Enter the initial y position."></td>
        </tr>
        </div>
        <tr>
        <td><button class=green type="submit">Submit</button><button class=green type="reset">Reset</button>
    <td>
        </tr>    
    </form>
        <tr>
            <td>{% block submit %}{% endblock %}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {% endblock %}    
        </td>
       <td>
     {% block content %}{% endblock %}  
        </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
          <td colspan="2"> <p> This demonstration shows the projectile motion of object launched at from a position (<math><mrow><msub><mi>x</mi><mi>o</mi></msub><mo>,</mo><msub><mi>y</mi><mi>o</mi></msub></mrow></math>) with initial velocity (<math><mrow><msub><mi>v</mi><mi>o</mi></msub></mrow></math>) at an angle (<math><mi>&theta;</mi></math>). Here are the <a href= "{{url_for('static', filename='projectilemotion.pdf')}}">equations</a> we use for this demonstration.</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I figured out another way using html write in a plotly.go object and displaying it in a iframe on my html file.